# use function from main activity in another java file

Tags: java, android

I’m trying to call a method in my main Activity from another file, but it crashes. I can easily do this the other way. Can you not invoke methods of the main Activity from another Activity?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
….
……..
……

public void my_function(String a){
//do some stuff
 }

}



package main;
public class stuff extends Activity {
….
….
…
MainActivity run = new MainActivity();
run.my_function(String a);
 }
}
```

Comment: Please post actual code, because formed that way, this "question" it's absolutely unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a method to get called from different classes, create a seperate class
and encapsulate the logic. See an activity more as a view controller, the logic
should be somewhere else.

Sorry for my english, hope this helps. 
Steve

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line

```
MainActivity run = new MainActivity();
```

you never instantiate Activities directly, you need to instantiate them through `Intent` objects.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
```

If you want to instantiate a **new** activity use an Intent. If you want to call `my_function` in an activity that is already instantiated, you need first to get a pointer to that Activity, which in Android is a little bit tricky.

Additionally, the fact that you want to call a method from another activity is a sign of bad design, or that you don't fully understand the Android way of doing things.

Think if there's any other approach you can use for your purpose.